# remove 2 common array item javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, arraylist

I have 2 arrays

```
let arryOne =
[
  {
   'catRefId' : "200531-2"
  },
  {
   'catRefId' : "201425-1"
 },
 {
   'catRefId' : "201423-1"
 },
 ]

let arryTwo =
 [
   {

    'removeId' : "200531-2"
   },
   {
    'removeId' : "201425-1"
   },
  ]
```

I tried below code but not working

```
let _finalArray = [];
for (let index = 0; index < arryOne.length; index++) {
_finalArray = arryOne.filter(obj => obj.catRefId === arryTwo[index].removeId)
}
```

Comment: It's not at the same index. You need to use `Array.find()` instead. Or you first create a Set of ids to remove, then check is the set has() the id.

Comment: You probably don't need the for loop at all if you're using filter.

Comment: @ChrisG  evolutionxbox can you post answer so i can get idea

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#examples)

```js
let arryTwo = [{ removeId: '200531-2' }, { removeId: '201425-1'}];
let arryOne = [{ catRefId: '200531-2' }, { catRefId: '201425-1'},{ catRefId: '201423-1' }];

const idsToRemove = new Set(arryTwo.map(({ removeId }) => removeId));

const _finalArray = arryOne.filter((item) => !idsToRemove.has(item.catRefId));
console.log(_finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:
First we extract the Ids from the second array.
Then we filter all matching references.

What's left is all references not present in arryTwo.

```js
let _finalArray = [];
_finalArray = arryOne.filter(obj => !arryTwo.map(obj => obj.removeId).includes(obj.catRefId));
```

Comment: although this solves the problem it does the `map` call in every iteraton of the filter